# Modify fabric.Image.fromURL after initial load using Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm using theFabric.js library, and I've seen a lot of examples on how to load an image from a URL using Image.fromURL. Almost every example assigns the image to a variable, using this general setup:

```
var bgnd = new fabric.Image.fromURL(bgndURL, function(oImg){
    oImg.hasBorders = false;
    oImg.hasControls = false;
    // ... Modify other attributes
    canvas.insertAt(oImg,0);
});
```

I've found that the attributes of the image can only be modified within the callback function when the image finishes loading. Is there a way to modify its attributes at a later time? I tried changing the attributes of the `bgnd` variable directly but it doesn't do anything.

```
bgnd.set({left: 20, top: 50});
canvas.renderAll();
```

or

```
bgnd.rotation = 45;
canvas.renderAll();
```

they don't do anything. What's the point of assigning the fabric.Image object to the `bgnd` variable if this variable can't be accessed at a later time? Or am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: If I answered your question below please choose this as the answer, or let me know if you are still having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you insert the image using

```
canvas.insertAt(oImg,0);

canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
myImg= canvas.getActiveObject();
```

You should be able to change it using

```
myImg.rotation = 45;
```

Remember to create the myImg variable as a global variable.  Outside of the image fromURL function  [Modify After Load Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdwtgsy7/)

Comment: This definitely doesn't work if you want to access the variable right after `fabric.Image.fromURL()` (not access it from a function). Whereas that's not the case for `fabric.Image()`.  [fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/sinq/wdwtgsy7/28/)

Comment: "Is there a way to modify its attributes at a later time?"  Accessing right after is not part of the OP's question. In your example the alert is happening before the image is actually loaded. I am not sure why you would want to load an image with certain attributes and change them directly after without user interaction.  You might as well load it with the desired attributes.

Comment: "I am not sure why you would want to load an image with certain attributes and change them directly after without user interaction."
Not change them, but use them. Example:
The loaded image must be added to a group which has another object itself. Now the second object must use the dimension of the image that was supposed to be loaded right after it was called. Why? because its data (such as width and height) is needed right away. 
Two ways to make it happen: one to forget image.fromURL, second is: 
(http://jsfiddle.net/wdwtgsy7/30/)