# Object with ImageFromUrl - Javascript - FabricJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying http://fabricjs.com/ for a project. I succesfully create a canvas, and load some images with fabric.Image.fromURL function, but now i need to edit this image with other Fabric functions, my problem is this: I want to convert the image in an object, like in the Fabric tutorial

```
var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  angle: 30,
  opacity: 0.85
});
```

but when i try with an image load from Url, it doesn't works, in the tutorial appears like this:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('my_image.png', function(oImg) {
  // scale image down, and flip it, before adding it onto canvas
  oImg.scale(0.5).setFlipX(true);
  canvas.add(oImg);
});
```

i need something like this:

```
var img = new fabric.Image.fromURL('my_image.png', function(oImg) {...
```

because I want to apply filters to the image outside of the callback function, but I don't have idea how.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439561/modify-fabric-image-fromurl-after-initial-load-using-fabric-js

Comment: That answer is good if you only have one image or one object i think, But, in my case, i need to load more images, and none of them is selectable, so, with that solution the object will be the last image loaded @Piou

Comment: Before your loop, instantiate an array `var myImgs = [];`, in your loop, just after the call to `fromUrl()`, do this: `myImgs.push(canvas.getActiveObject());`.